# CAS login-webflow modified adding view during ticket check

Tags: java, cas

I modified the login-webflow after the "sendTicketGrantingTicket".
I made a transition and redirect all to a page with 3 buttons. When I click on one button I continue the flow, with other buttons make some Actions and continue or reboot to login page.
The configuration of login-webflow added is:

```
    <action-state id="sendTicketGrantingTicket">
     <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
     <transition to="testMy" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="testMy">
     <evaluate expression="testMyAction.doBind(ticketRegistry, flowRequestContext, messageContext)" />
     <transition on="success" to="serviceCheck" />
     <transition on="question" to="viewMyQuestionForm" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="viewMyQuestionForm" view="casMyQuestionView">
     <transition on="choice1" to="myChoice1" />
     <transition on="choice2" to="myChoice2" />
     <transition on="choiceContinue" to="serviceCheck" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="myChoice1">
     <evaluate expression="testMyAction.myChoice1(ticketRegistry, flowRequestContext, messageContext)" />
     <transition to="viewLoginForm" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="myChoice2">
     <evaluate expression="testMyAction.myChoice2(ticketRegistry, flowRequestContext, messageContext)" />
     <transition to="serviceCheck" />
    </action-state>
```

The piece of jsp is:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="${loginTicket}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
            <input class="btn-submit" style="margin-left: 3px" name="_eventId_choice1"
                accesskey="l"
                value="<spring:message code="screen.welcome.button.choice1" />"
                tabindex="4" type="submit" />
            <input class="btn-submit" style="margin-left: 3px" name="_eventId_choice2"
                accesskey="l"
                value="<spring:message code="screen.welcome.button.choice2" />"
                tabindex="4" type="submit" />
            <input class="btn-submit" style="margin-left: 3px" name="_eventId_choiceContinue"
                accesskey="l"
                value="<spring:message code="screen.welcome.button.choiceContinue" />"
                tabindex="4" type="submit" />
```

Now in testMyAction.java I have doBind, myChoice1, myChoice2 methods doing only a System.out.

When doBind answer with a "success", all goes normally.

When doBind answer "question", I see the 3 button page and, if I click on the choiceContinue button, a CAS error raise up.

**ticketGrantingticketId cannot be null**
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)

I think must pass the grantingTicket throw the view. In this manner It could be present during the flow... But how? And, is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself...
saving the TGT during doBind and put it in RequestScope during testMyAction.myChoiceXXX